# networkmanager wifi not connecting, wpa_supplicant is ok

Tags: wireless, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to setup access point on one computer and connect from another.
Here is access point config (/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot.nmconnection):

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=590dd05e-61eb-41e0-aa4f-b838c5675d77
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
interface-name=wlan0
timestamp=1675612177

[wifi]
band=a
channel=149
mode=ap
ssid=MyAccessPoint_5G

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=SuperSecret

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=ignore

[proxy]
```

This config was created by

```
nmcli wifi hotspot ifname wlan0 ssid MyAccessPoint_5G password SuperSecret
```

On another computer (notebook) I am trying to connect to this hotspot using nm-applet.
It tries for several seconds and fails, asking for password again.

Here is entry that it creates at (/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyAccessPoint_5G.nmconnection)

```
[connection]
id=MyAccessPoint_5G
uuid=0a595f1c-925c-4904-861e-a96e21fbad24
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp5s0

[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=MyAccessPoint_5G

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=SuperSecret

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]
```

Here are logs from journal:

```
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 wpa_supplicant[1211]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="MyAcessPoing_5G"
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 wpa_supplicant[1211]: wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 (SSID='MyAcessPoing_5G' freq=5745 MHz)
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 kernel: wlp5s0: authenticate with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 kernel: wlp5s0: send auth to a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 (try 1/3)
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612911.8143] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612911.8144] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 wpa_supplicant[1211]: wlp5s0: Trying to associate with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 (SSID='MyAcessPoing_5G' freq=5745 MHz)
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 kernel: wlp5s0: authenticated
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 kernel: wlp5s0: associate with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 (try 1/3)
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612911.8227] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612911.8228] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 kernel: wlp5s0: RX AssocResp from a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 (capab=0x8111 status=43 aid=0)
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 kernel: wlp5s0: a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 denied association (code=43)
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 wpa_supplicant[1211]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 status_code=43
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 wpa_supplicant[1211]: wlp5s0: SME: Deauth request to the driver failed
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 wpa_supplicant[1211]: BSSID a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 wpa_supplicant[1211]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MyAcessPoing_5G" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612911.8710] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Feb 05 19:01:51 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612911.8711] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
Feb 05 19:01:53 basilioe480 dhclient[6958]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xe42bf937)
Feb 05 19:01:56 basilioe480 dhclient[6958]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xe42bf937)
Feb 05 19:02:01 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612921.8739] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Feb 05 19:02:01 basilioe480 NetworkManager[1173]: <info>  [1675612921.8740] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
```

I created a simple config using wpa_passphrase:

```
network={
    ssid="MyAccessPoint_5G"
    #psk="SuperSecret"
    psk=8c2193dd5c26d1ce18553fdd17e3b1a93af3650f5d1fecaabf7efe2f4c162122
}
```

And when I start wpa_supplicant by hand it connects without problem.

```
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -cmyap.conf -iwlp5s0

Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: Could not set interface 'p2p-dev-wlp5s0' UP
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlp5s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
p2p-dev-wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface
wlp5s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 (SSID='MyAccessPoint_5G' freq=5745 MHz)
wlp5s0: Trying to associate with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 (SSID='MyAccessPoint_5G' freq=5745 MHz)
wlp5s0: Associated with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp5s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to a8:39:2f:50:86:b7 completed [id=0 id_str=]
```

Access point is Orange Pi Zero 2 (Allwinner H616 64-bit high-performance Quad-core Cortex-A53 processor, AW859A Chip Support IEEE 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac), running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (aarch64)

Notebook is Thinkpad e480, wireless card is Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165, running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Try with group and pairwise set to aes under wifi security on the hotspot

Comment: # nmcli connection modify Hotspot 802-11-wireless-security.group aes 802-11-wireless-security.pairwise ccmp
Error: failed to modify 802-11-wireless-security.group: 'aes' not among [wep40, wep104, tkip, ccmp]
Changed to group to tkimp and pairwise to aes, with no effect

Comment: Error: failed to modify 802-11-wireless-security.pairwise: 'aes' not among [tkip, ccmp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved, once I change proto to `wpa`.
By default, Hotspot was created with proto set to `rsn`.

There was no setting for proto in NetworkManager configuration, I've figured it from hotspot logs:

```
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3346] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MyAccessPoint_5G'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3348] Config: added 'mode' value '2'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3349] Config: added 'frequency' value '5745'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3349] Config: added 'freq_list' value '5745'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3350] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3351] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3351] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3352] Config: added 'proto' value 'RSN'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3353] Config: added 'pairwise' value 'CCMP'
Feb 07 15:10:52 bedroomap NetworkManager[641]: <info>  [1675782652.3354] Config: added 'group' value 'CCMP'
```

I've added proto wpa and all worked:

```
# nmcli connection modify Hotspot 802-11-wireless-security.proto wpa
```

Comment: dude, yes! This worked for me, AP on a Raspberry Pi.